# Como subrayar solo unas letras de una palabra con CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Lo que deseo es subrayar los menús pero solamente **las primeras 3 letras de cada menú** con CSS. Estoy usando: `text-decoration: underline #A1E26C;`
pero lo subraya todo.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Agrega un `span` con las 3 primeras letras y aplicas el estilo e esa etiqueta _(span)_ , es decir  `<a><span>Reg</span>istro</a>`

Comment: Por favor agrega el código que has usado...

Answer (score 3):

Para hacer lo que pides lo más sencillo es envolver el contenido que quieras subrayar en una etiqueta `<span></span>`.

```css
.sub {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="sub">Tit</span>ulo</h1>
```

`<span></span>` Es una etiqueta de HTML que establece un **elemento en línea** al que puedes agregar atributos propios de este lenguaje, tales como `class=""` o `id=""`.

Estos atributos usados desde CSS te sirven para añadir las propiedades de estilo que necesites y se aplicaran al contenido al que el span envuelve.

Existen **pseudo-elementos** en CSS que nos permiten seleccionar también solo determinado contenido.

```
p:first-letter{} /*Aplica las propiedades a la primera letra de cada p*/
p:first-line{} /*Aplica las propiedades a la primera linea de cada p*/
```

Answer (score 2):

La mejor forma seria usar simplemente un `span` personalizado.

Si quieres lograr un efecto similar, pero en vede poner un `bottom-border` a 3 letras, seria usando un ancho `width` personalizable

**Ejemplo `span`:**

```css
/* Default reset */

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: green;
}

span {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}


/* Efecto hover - span */

a:hover span {
  border-bottom: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!-- Usando span -->
<a href="#"><span>Hol</span>a Mundo</a>
```

Ahora si deseas usar un ancho personalizable te dejo un ejemplo alternativo usando `before`.

**Ejemplo `before`:**

```css
/* Default reset */

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: green;
}

.under-line:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  width: 30px;
  /* Ancho personabizable */
}

.under-line {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}


/* Efecto hover - :before */

a:hover.under-line:before {
  border-bottom: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!-- Usando :before -->
<a href="#" class="under-line">Usando before</a>
```

Comment: @Mariano si coincido contigo, era simplemente una alternativa para lograr algún efecto similar como alternativa, la mejor forma desde mi punto de visto es usar simplemente un `<span>`. Modificare mi respuesta.

Comment: Ok, ahora entiendo mejor... Quizás le sirve a quien use una fuente de ancho fijo, y la línea con `3ch`. Ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/rsxwLdkw/

Comment: @Mariano correcto, ya modifiqué mi respuesta. Sirve más para una fuente de ancho fijo. Un saludo.

Answer (score -2):

En html5 con css3 puedes utilizar la etiqueta

```html
<mark>Texto subrayado</mark>
```

te dejo el link de w3schools [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_mark).

Comment: El comportamiento por omisión de `<mark>` en la mayoría de los navegadores es resaltar, no subrayar.

Comment: Vengo de probarlo en los 3 principales navegadores y subraya